# Python Pandas: copy several columns at specific row from one dataframe to another with different names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe1 with columns a,b,c,d with 5 rows.
I also have another dataframe2 with columns e,f,g,h
Let's say I want to copy columns a,b in row 3 from dataframe1 to columns f,g in row 3 at dataframe2.

I tried to use this code:
dataframe2.loc[3,['f','g']] = dataframe1.loc[3,['a','b']].

The results was NaN in dataframe2.
Any ideas how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is convert to numpy array for avoid alignment data by columns names:

```
dataframe2.loc[3,['f','g']] = dataframe1.loc[3,['a','b']].values
```

**Sample**:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abcdef'),
                           'b':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                           'c':[7,8,9,4,2,3]})
print (dataframe1)

   a  b  c
0  a  4  7
1  b  5  8
2  c  4  9
3  d  5  4
4  e  5  2
5  f  4  3

dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame({'f':list('HIJK'),
                           'g':[0,0,7,1],
                           'h':[0,1,0,1]})
print (dataframe2)
   f  g  h
0  H  0  0
1  I  0  1
2  J  7  0
3  K  1  1

dataframe2.loc[3,['f','g']] = dataframe1.loc[3,['a','b']].values
print (dataframe2)
   f  g  h
0  H  0  0
1  I  0  1
2  J  7  0
3  d  5  1
```

Comment: Great! thanks, this is the answer I have looked for.